# Winforms Listbox or Listview image and text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not very experienced on c#. I'm working with winforms and I'm looking for a way to create something like a list of elements with this template  , something like the autocompletion list of visual studio.
Is it possible to do? Shall I use listbox or listview?

EDIT
Sorry my question wasn't clear I don't want to create an autocomplete but what i want to create is something like [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/images/csharp_2010/intellisense_console.gif) a list of things with an icon next to the text of that thing.

Comment: [AutoComplete TextBox in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx) Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you can create custom `UserControl` or create a `Form` and put `ListBox` in it. If you use `From` be sure that you change border style layout, just set it to none. After creation for use it you should create form and show it where you want like this:

```
FrmAutoComplete x = new FrmAutoComplete();
x.Show();
```

you can put this form in ToolTipItem and show it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

THis is a quick and dirty example of using images in your Listview control. Since I don;t have a lot of information about what you plan to do, I tried to keep is simple.

In short, you need to load some images into one of the ImageLists (Large or Small) built into the Listview control and assign them keys so that you can assign them to specific list items as you add them.

The trick to this is determining which image to use for a specific list item (assuming there are different images assigned to different list items depending on some differentiating factor. For this example, I used an arbitrary assignment of "cars" or "trucks," and simply decided that the first five items in the list would be cars, and the last five would be trucks. I then assigned each image appropriately, using the image key as I added each listview item. You can do this for more complex scenarios, and when using the image key, it does not matter what order the items are added.

For this use case, you will want to create or use images with dimensions of 16 x 16 pixels. I went ahead and added two images to my project resource file, then simply accessed them using the project `Properties.Resources` name space. There are other ways to do this as well, but this is the most convenient for me.

Hope that helps.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string CAR_IMAGE_KEY = "Car";
    static string TRUCK_IMAGE_KEY = "Truck";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetupListview();
        this.LoadListView();
    }


    private void SetupListview()
    {
        var imgList = new ImageList();
        imgList.Images.Add("Car", Properties.Resources.jpgCarImage);
        imgList.Images.Add("Truck", Properties.Resources.jpgTruckImage);

        var lv = this.listView1;
        lv.View = View.List;
        lv.SmallImageList = imgList;            
    }


    private void LoadListView()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            string currentImageKey = CAR_IMAGE_KEY;
            if(i > 5) currentImageKey = TRUCK_IMAGE_KEY;
            var item = this.listView1.Items.Add("Item" + i.ToString(), currentImageKey);
        }
    }
```